# What is the fastest way to parse large csv files where xy data is appended with a header?

Tags: python

I need to load in csv files where scan data is appended to the file with a scan header. I need to extract the (1) file header, (2) the test headers, and (3) the data by columns. The data generally looks like this:

```
// ************** HEADER START ***************  
// Create Date: Fri, Apr 29, 2022, 7:04:23 PM ******  
// Bias: 1  
// Sweep: 2  
// ************** HEADER END ***************  
   
  
   
//******* START TEST HEADER *******  
//Timestamp: 003734105862  
//Temp: 80.774   
//******* END TEST HEADER *******  
  
-0.00348663 -1.11998    0.166191  
-0.00322723 -1.11001    0.221562  
-0.00294685 -1.09998    0.276954  
  
  
   
//******* START TEST HEADER *******  
//Timestamp: 003734105862  
//Temp: 80.774  
//******* END TEST HEADER *******  
   
-0.00424957 -1.14997    0  
-0.00403214 -1.14   0.0554025  
-0.00376701 -1.12998    0.110801  
-0.0026741  -1.08997    0.332338
```

The file header and individual test headers are reliably uniform. The data will always be in 3 columns, but the number of data rows may vary from file to file, and possibly within the file (though less likely). Generally speaking, the test data will have 120 rows, each file may have upwards of 2,000 tests, and I have to load anywhere from 16 to 256 files.

While I would like to use `pd.read_csv()`, I would have to know where the test headers are and how many data points there are (as I understand it). I could read in the csv as a list and iterate to find the indexes of test starts, but at that point I wonder if it makes sense to go to Pandas or just work with the list I already have.

My current approach (in abbreviated form) looks like this:

1. Read csv into list using `csv.reader()`
2. Parse the first n lines list to get experiment header
3. Use list comprehension to find row indexes of where tests are
   `scan_here = [i for i,x in enumerate(csv_list) if x == ["//******* START TEST HEADER *******"]]`
4. Calculate the number of data rows based on the separation of scan_here values `n_pts = scan_here[i+1] - scan_here[i] - blank_rows`) to generate a list with row indexes of the tests and the number of data points: `test_idx += [[r, n_pts]]`
5. Iterate through tst_idx to parse the test header (not shown) and extract data

```
    def get_scanData(csv_list, tst_idx[0]):
    ''' Returns {i, v, t}'''
        r0 = r[0] + 7   # jv data start
        rn = r0 + r[1]  # jv data end
    
        current = np.array([float(row[0]) for row in csv_list[r0:rn]])
        voltage = np.array([float(row[1]) for row in csv_list[r0:rn]])
        elpsTime = np.array([float(row[2]) for row in csv_list[r0:rn]])
    
        scanData = {'i': current,
                    'v': voltage,
                    't': elpsTime}
        
        return scanData
```

I know I'm iterating through the csv list a few times. The only place I feel like I could speed it up is to read it in, find the indexes and send only the data portion over to `pd.read_csv()` to parse. Is there any other way to approach this to speed it up? I feel like no matter what, I will have to iterate over the list at least once to find where the test start rows are and how many data points there are.

Comment: Rather than process data after finding out where it is, what not go line by line and process it as it appears?

Comment: I guess because I wasn't thinking of the `csv.reader()` as line by line.